# Live Agent - Automatic Routing of Incoming Request to other agent

Tags: liveagent

is it possible in Live Agent: 
If an agent is not responding to the incoming new chat request within 60 seconds, to transfer the chat to another agent ? 
So that we dont keep the customer on waiting mode for a long time.